# How to compare two integers in a jinja2 if statement?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I need to compare two variables in a `jinja2` if statement using Flask.

How can I do a simple `<` comparison?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easily thankfully:

```
{% if (foo < bar) %}
```

Docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#if

Comment: The problem is even in the exact above syntax, the '<' is registered as part of the html and causes an error in rendering.

Comment: @Alex please [edit] your question to include the error you get from rendering.